# ajax always go in the error part of the code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm not very good with ajax but to use one of my jquery plugins, I must do a little call in ajax. The problem is that it always go in the error handling of the function and I don't know why. Since I'm using Visual Web Developper Express, javascript debugging doesn't work.

Here is the jquery function:

```
$('.auto-submit-star').rating({
            callback: function (value, link) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Recipe/Rate",
                    data: $("#rate").serialize(),
                    dataType: "text/plain",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response != 'false') {
                            alert('Your vote has been saved');
                        } else {
                            alert('You already voted for this recipe!');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert('There is an error');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Then, it goes in the controler. I've debugged this part and it works, it saves the good value in the database then return "false" or "" depending if the user has already voted or not.

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Rate(FormCollection form)
        {
            var rate = Convert.ToInt32(form["Score"]);
            var id = Convert.ToInt32(form["IDRecipe"]);

            //On valide si l'utilisateur a déja voté
            Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
            var existingVote = db.StarRatings.Where(a => a.IDRecipe == id).Where(b => b.IDUser == userGuid).FirstOrDefault();

            if (existingVote != null)
                return Content("false");

            StarRating rating = new StarRating();
            rating.IDRecipe = id;
            rating.IDUser = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
            rating.Score = rate;

            var recipe = db.Recipes.Where(a => a.IDRecipe == id).First();
            recipe.StarRatings.Add(rating);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Content("");
        }
```

Anyone can tell me why I always receive the message "There is an error" and it never goes in the "success" part of the ajax call? Do I need to return something special in the controler?

***EDIT***

Here is a screenshot of the response variable in the internet explorer debugger that one of the comment make me discover.

[image: Screenshot!]

Thanks!

Comment: you can debug javascript in your browser, and you can use fiddler to see whats getting transmitted

Comment: Can't you print out the error message?

Comment: If its hitting the error function in the ajax call then it means there is an error happening in your server side function. Use fiddler to see what the error is on the response.

Comment: When I do alert(response); instead of alert('There is an error'), I get a message box with this inside: [object Object]. @KeithNicholas, how do I do that? I put the breakpoint but it doesn't stop and I've read that the support for debugging wasn't supported with MVC. How can I use jsfiddle to debug a controler that is on my local computer???

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: it has nothing to do with visual studio,  debugging javascript is completely separate on the browser.

Comment: eg, on chrome, CTRNL-SHIFT-J

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer.

Comment: Ok I've been able to debug and see the content of the response variable. Everything seems ok, I will update my question in a minute...

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the return of the controller action and making sure that the action method runs to the end without any exceptions?  Just because the data is saved doesn't mean that an exception isn't occurring at some point after the data is saved.

Comment: Also try returning something besides an empty string such as "Bob".  Even though the response status is "OK" the error event will still run if jquery cannot parse the result.  Usually that only applies to json/xml, but it is possible that plain text will fail on an empty string.  Just a guess.

Comment: yes I put the whole function in a try catch and no exception are thrown. In fact, it does go in the "error" part of the jquery function even with the "return Content('false')" of the controler;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this and fix it by using `text` instead of `text/plain`.  My understanding of the cause is that the browser is first interpreting the response as HTML and throwing an error as a result.  I can run the code in console and see the parse error when it encountered my text "Blah" that my controller returned and says "unexpected token B".

I couldn't find any solid documentation on this though other than a reference to the issue in Firefox, but I am using Chrome and had the same problem.  The workaround was to use `xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");` mentioned here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ You may need to do that instead if your browser still doesn't like text.

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Recipe/Rate",
                    data: $("#rate").serialize(),
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response != 'false') {
                            alert('Your vote has been saved');
                        } else {
                            alert('You already voted for this recipe!');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert('There is an error');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: nice to know that you could reproduce the bug. I will try that tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following changes:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public JsonResult Rate(int Score, int IDRecipe)
{
    //On valide si l'utilisateur a déja voté
    Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
    var existingVote = db.StarRatings.Where(a => a.IDRecipe == IDRecipe).Where(b => b.IDUser == userGuid).FirstOrDefault();

    if (existingVote != null)
        return Json(false);

    StarRating rating = new StarRating();
    rating.IDRecipe = IDRecipe;
    rating.IDUser = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
    rating.Score = Score;

    var recipe = db.Recipes.Where(a => a.IDRecipe == IDRecipe).First();
    recipe.StarRatings.Add(Score);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(true);
}
```

And your JavaScript call:

```
$('.auto-submit-star').rating({
    callback: function (value, link) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Recipe/Rate",
            data: { IDRecipe: GetRecipeID(), Score: GetScore() },
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The `data` object value passed to the `$.ajax` call will be appended to the URL as a set of query parameters, resulting in a URL similar to `/Recipe/Rate?IDRecipe=123&Score=123` which is interpreted by the MVC code to find the appropriate parameters to initialize in the call to the `Rate` method.  Similarly, the `Json(true)` and `Json(false)` returns in the `Rate` method will be converted to a JSON-encoded string and returned as the body of the response.

Comment: Seems interesting, I will try that tomorow

Comment: Where does the GetRecipeID and GetScore come from?